# How to Browser the image set the Jlabel in java

Tags: java

i am tried to browser the image and set into Jlabel but. i got the error of 
   BufferedImage thumbanail = Thumbnails.of(image).size(250,200).asBufferedImage(); this line of the code error indicate the size . jLabel 7 i have changed the variable name imagelabel here image needs to diplay after browser the image

[image]

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JFileChooser ch = new JFileChooser();
        ch.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = ch.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
        jTextField5.setText(filename);     

        try {
                File image = new File(filename);                  
                BufferedImage thumbanail = Thumbnails.of(image).size(250,200).asBufferedImage();
                ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(thumbanail, "jpeg",os);
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                for(int readnum;(readnum = is.read(buf))!=-1;)
                {
                        bos.write(buf,0,readnum);
                }
                    ImageIcon viewimage = new ImageIcon(thumbanail);
                    imagelabel.setIcon(viewimage);           

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(emploee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can choose the picture and resize that to fill the JLabel and add to it as ImageIcon. if you don't scale the image will be cropped.

```
  JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    if(fc.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile());
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new 
        ImageIcon(img).getImage().getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        yourLabel.setIcon(imageIcon);
      }
```

Here 20,20 are width and height of image you need to set.